# Unable to create folder on network drive

Tags: c#, networking, directory

I'm trying to create a folder on network drive through windows application in C#.

The problem which I'm facing is that while the .exe is getting installed it opens up a window and asks for the network drive path. When I provide the path and click on "Ok" it doesn't create a folder. I checked it in the network drive that folder doesn't exist.

When the exe gets installed and I launch the application and this time if I provide a N/w drive path. It creates the folder with no problem.

Same window page gets opened both the time and the same code gets executed but at the time of installation it doesn't create folder on network drive.

I used **System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sFilePath)**   'Create directory if doesn't exist.

I don't think it's related to permission because I'm able to create network folder through the application after the .exe gets installed successfully.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are talking about the problem occurring while the exe is getting installed. Is your program installing an exe? The exe is getting installed how? Are you getting an exception from CreateDirectory?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to go after here.

Are you accessing a mapped drive?

If you program is running under UAC with elevated privileges, then you will not have access to you mapped drives, in this case provide the full unc path.